# Unity, Git: local ignore file not ignoring anything

Tags: git, gitignore, unity-game-engine

I have a .gitignore file copied from [here](http://kleber-swf.com/the-definitive-gitignore-for-unity-projects/) in the root of my repository, but none of the specified files or directories are being ignored. I have reverted back to right after the initial commit, added the .gitignore file, created a new unity project, and immediately had 90 added files mostly in the /Library directory.
All of the files are new, so the problem is not that it is not removing newly-ignored files.
Am I missing some step where I point git to the ignore file? In the past I have not had to deal with anything like that. Is the local ignore file overridden by a global one?

Comment: local one usually override gloabal one, there must be sth wrong

Comment: Is the repository's root directory also the top level directory of the Unity project, or did you create the Unity project inside the repository? Try moving the `.gitignore` into the top level directory of the project.

Comment: The project is in a ./source folder in the repository. That seems to have been the issue. Why does the .gitignore cascade down the file structure if it is in the unity project root but not if it is in the repository root..?

Answer (score 0):

Becuase of this 
`[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore`

you can put the gitignore in other folders, as the same time, you must config the config file `.git/config`

All your config is in it.